# Representing colors

Tags: c#, .net, colors, terminal, console

I'm currently trying to create some sort of graphical interface framework for consoles and terminal emulators, similar to [lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/), but with a more declarative approach, however I stumpled upon something that is giving me headaches for days now: *Colors*.

What I'm looking forward to is a way to represent colors as well as color palettes independently of the underlying implementation and scheme (*ANSI*, *Indexed*, *24-bit* for VGA, xterm, Windows..). My initial idea was to create a simple struct that represents a color in the RGB color space:

```
public struct Color {
    public byte R, G, B;
}
```

... and declare a predefined set of colors such as `public static readonly Color Black = new Color(0, 0, 0);` However this might won't work because e.g. *red* on *xterm* is not the same as *red* in a *Windows Console*. Then I thought about using `enum`, but here I'm unable to define what value a color exactly has.

What would be a possible way to achive this? Are there other color spaces that might be more suitable to represent colors than *RGB*?

Comment: It sounds like what you are really wanting is for a single color "name" to be able to have different definitions depending on context?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Somewhat, yes. But the named colors should only be 'presets', because they make no sense e.g. with indexed colors. Also, it would be nice if they could be combine e.g: Color Yellow = Color.Red | Color.Green. Does this make sense somehow?

Comment: Yea, sounds like you may need to override an operator in the `Color` struct to get color "mixing". As for different constants, I'd create static classes like `XTermColors` that'd have the correct RGB values defined for "Red" for each environment. You may be able to somehow use inheritance/interfaces to provide a common set of color names that can be used anywhere, with the specific "implementation" swapped in depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, it would be nice if they could be combine e.g: Color Yellow =
> Color.Red | Color.Green. Does this make sense somehow?

If Color is simply an integer, then Color.Yellow == Color.Red | Color.Green works without any extra code (it's equivalent to 0xFFFF00 == 0xFF0000 | 0x00FF00). If you want color to have separate R, G and B properties, then you could do some fancy operator overloading and have that still work.

> What I'm looking forward to is a way to represent colors as well as color palettes independently of the underlying implementation and scheme (ANSI, Indexed, 24-bit for VGA, xterm, Windows..). My initial idea was to create a simple struct that represents a color in the RGB color space:
>
> ...
>
> Are there other color spaces that might be more suitable to represent
> colors than RGB?

I'm a fan of this one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space

This explains why:

http://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/the-rainbow-is-dead-long-live-the-rainbow-series-outline/